# Integrate a Welcome message in header in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, function, authentication

in my wordpress site https://suonareaorecchio.com I have a login/logout button in the header, created with this code in functions.php

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_login_logout_link', 10, 2);
    function add_login_logout_link($items, $args) {
    ob_start();
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    wp_loginout('index.php');
    } else {
    wp_loginout( get_permalink( get_page_by_title( 'La mia pagina' ) ) );
    }
    $loginoutlink = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    $items .= '<li>'. $loginoutlink .'</li>';
return $items;
}
add_filter( 'login_url', 'my_login_page', 10, 2 );
    function my_login_page( $login_url, $redirect ) {
    $url = get_permalink( get_page_by_title( 'Login' ) );
    return $url . '?redirect_to=' . $redirect;
}
```

That creates correctly this Login/Logout button in the top right header.
[image: Loging/logout in top right header]

I want to integrate a welcome message that says Hi user! (with link to a specific /profile/ page) and a sub menu with the logout link (with home page redirect).

To JUST create the welcome message I found this, but it creates a message in the page, not header.

```
add_action( 'loop_start', 'personal_message_when_logged_in' );
    function personal_message_when_logged_in() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) : 
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
echo 'Ciao ' . $current_user->user_login . '!';
else :
    echo 'Non personalize message (No clue what to put!)';
endif;
}
```

Basically the result I'd like to recreate would be this:

[image: welcome message plus logout submenu]

Do you know how can I integrate the two codes to have something like the second image? If you're kind may I have the final code to copy and paste since unfortunately I'm a noob?

Thanks so much for helping.

Comment: Open up your header.php or where ever your menu code and ask if user logged in with is_user_logged_in function. If so displays the message.

Comment: There is no hook available to to that. `wp_head()` adds such content right at the top and `loop_start` is to late. IMO, I see not other way that editing template files. You should do this in a child theme though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to edit you header.php (wp-blog-header.php) page instead of the function.php one. You also have a footer php page if you're interested in changing the footer of the page.

Take a look at this [video](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CC4QtwIwAw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DW_o_WeQyX-Q&ei=zq44VabPEILlaurXgbgM&usg=AFQjCNEjYK_0ZasiSFY-f5uVDw-yatFqow&bvm=bv.91427555,d.bGg) .

The default location for header and footer should be : wp-content/themes/mytheme